# mongodb writing use cpu fully but not use memory at all

Tags: mongodb, memory, cpu-usage

I don't know why but very interesting stats shows.

First of all, I installed MongoDB on ec2, c5.4xlarge.

And I make some test write on the DB.

The funny thing is,, when I wrote 10 documents concurrently, MongoDB uses almost 100% CPU per core, but no memory increases at all!!

If I knew correctly, mongodb writes at first memory, so what I expect is increasing memory usage.

In order to reduce CPU usage per core, what I did is as follows:

- disable atime
- make MongoDB data folder running on xfs file system.
- store MongoDB data on EBS with provisioning for increasing IOPS
- upgrade glibc new latest version

What I used MongoDB version is 4.4 and used engine is WiredTiger.

Please help me if you have experience of running MongoDB on AWS for writing many many data continuously.

Below is my mongodb.conf

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: "/home/ubuntu/mongodb/data"
  journal:
    enabled: true
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 24

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: "/home/ubuntu/mongodb/log/mongod.log"

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

replication:
  replSetName: "rs-exchange"
```

Comment: Very interesting, but as it is now, it's too broad, and will be better suited for [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) or MongoDB [developers forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/)

Comment: Also, it is known that WiredTiger works better in XFS, and you should back up your claim about memory with a link. Check wired tiger docs.

Comment: @Minsky Thank you for your comment :) Yes, as I wrote, I have already used WiredTiger engine on XFS

Comment: Also you should share the replica set configuration to see if anything is wrong there

Comment: @MinskyThank you for your comment. Finally I found out that it's my problem. I mis-wrote some code, that is I used update_one instead of insert_one. For the case of update_one, I should have used indexes but I didn't... After applying index, then CPU usage has been decreased drastically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that a database uses either a specific amount of memory or that the amount of memory it uses is constantly growing.

For example, if I perform a [replace](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) operation in an infinite loop, naturally a lot of CPU would be consumed but the amount of memory used may well stay flat.

Comment: When you do a write operation in MongoDB the data is written to an in-memory journal. Unless you're running an ancient version, or the wrong setttings in a standalone version etc. Idk why you say that.

Comment: How does an in-memory journal cause unbounded memory consumption?

Comment: write operations are held in RAM and this is flushed to disk, if you run write ops, both should increase, not just CPU

Comment: Yes, and what does this have to do with *unbounded* memory consumption?

Comment: I don't care much what that is: in a write operation RAM usage should increase. If it does, then the answer you're giving is at the very least incomplete.

Comment: You understand the concept of fixed size buffers right?

Comment: Feel free to explain it in your answer, in the current state you just said "I don't know". And the second paragraph isn't even relevant.

Comment: Feel free to ask a question.

Comment: And if you don't know, why are you commenting here?

Comment: @D.SM Thank you for your comments. Normally, when I wrote something continuously, normally, memory usage also increase. The reason why my cpu is used fully, but not memory at all, is because I didn't use index. If you use replace operation, you also should use index for cpu usage, then you can confirm that there is decreased CPU usage drastically. :)

Comment: Adding indexes makes writes slower, not faster. Indexes speed up reads.

Comment: @D.SM It's partially true. Since indexes speed up reads, indexes are important for update and replace because it first searches wether delivered key exists or not